# Flex wrap is crashing everything

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im trying to **scrape** some divs but they are not wrapping and going out of my container

Html:

```
<div class="anime-list">
            {% for anime in response_data %}
                <div class="anime-item">
                    <div class="anime-cover" style="background-image: url({{ anime['cover'] }});" alt="">
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

And my css:

```
.anime-list {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
}

.anime-item {
    background-color: #000;
}

.anime-item div {
    width: 208px;
    height: 296px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

What my html ends like is like this

```
<div class="anime-list">
            
                <div class="anime-item">
                    <div class="anime-cover" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.animeapi.com/images/anime/4991.jpg);" alt="">
                </div>
            
                <div class="anime-item">
                    <div class="anime-cover" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.animeapi.com/images/anime/4937.jpg);" alt="">
                </div>
            
                <div class="anime-item">
                    <div class="anime-cover" style="background-image: url(https://cdn.animeapi.com/images/anime/5009.jpg);" alt="">
                </div>
            
        </div>
```

But it end up looking like this
[image: The anime-list has a gray bg to show it. Same for items sith black bg]

Is there any way to fix it?
Ive tried using `flex-direction: row;`, `flex: 1 1 0;`, `display: inline-flex;`. I could make it work using an img tag, but i need the div because i need to keep the image without distortion when resizing it.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your template is wrong, you are not closing your divs with class "anime-cover", if you fix that flex should work as intended.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt notice that